# Ping Pong simulation not correctly triggering function

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x

I'm new to OOP and am practicing putting together a little bit more complex programs using various classes and implementing principles like Inheritance.  I've created a Ping-Pong simulation that has a Player class which contains the probability that the player will win their serve.  Then I have a PingPong class which is a subclass of the super class RacquetSports.  Each instance is a single game, with the ability to change server, and record who won, and whether or not it was a shut-out.  Finally, I have a SimStats class whose purpose is to record the stats across "n" number of games.

My problem is that it seems like my `play_game` function is not correctly firing, when I place a print statement in there it never triggers.  My current result when running the whole program is that Player1 has 10 wins no shutouts, and Player2 has zero of both.

Finally, any suggestions on better OO practice would also be appreciated.  Here is my player class:

```
from random import random


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, prob_win):
        self.prob = prob_win
        self.points = 0

    def wins_serve(self):
        return self.prob >= random()

    def add_point(self):
        self.points += 1

    def get_score(self):
        return self.points
```

My RacquetSports class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from player import Player


class RacquetSport(object):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, prob1, prob2):
        self.player1 = Player(prob1)
        self.player2 = Player(prob2)
        self.server = self.player1

    def play_game(self):
        while not self.game_over():
            self.sim_point()

    @abstractmethod
    def type(self):
        pass

    def chg_server(self):
        if self.server == self.player1:
            self.server = self.player2
        else:
            self.server = self.player1

    def sim_point(self):
        if self.server.wins_serve():
            self.server.add_point()
        else:
            self.chg_server()

    @abstractmethod
    def game_over(self):
        pass

    def get_scores(self):
        return self.player1.get_score(), \
               self.player2.get_score()

    def return_stats(self):
        p1_score, p2_score = self.get_scores()
        print(p1_score, p2_score)
        won = 'p1'
        if p2_score > p1_score:
            won = 'p2'
        return won, self.__shutout(p1_score, p2_score)

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def __shutout(score1, score2):
        pass
```

My PingPong and SimStats classes, as well as my calling code:

```
from racquet import RacquetSport


class PingPong(RacquetSport):

    def type(self):
        return 'Ping Pong'

    def game_over(self):
        return self.player1.get_score == 11 or \
               self.player2.get_score == 11

    @staticmethod
    def __shutout(score1, score2):
        return abs(score1 - score2) == 11


class SimStats(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # First field is games won, second is shutouts.
        self.gms_won_p1 = [0] * 2
        self.gms_won_p2 = [0] * 2

    def update(self, game):
        won, shutout = game.return_stats()
        if won == 'p1':
            self.gms_won_p1[0] += 1
            if shutout:
                self.gms_won_p1[1] += 1
        else:
            self.gms_won_p2[0] += 1
            if shutout:
                self.gms_won_p2[1] += 1

    def print_results(self):
        tot_games = self.gms_won_p1 + self.gms_won_p2
        print('Wins for Player 1 = {} Shutouts = {}\n'
              'Wins for Player 2 = {} Shutouts = {}'.format(*tot_games))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = SimStats()
    for x in range(1, 11):
        game = PingPong(.5, .5)
        stats.update(game)
    stats.print_results()
```

Comment: note: you question is tagged `python-3.x` but you are using metaclasses `python-2.x`-style. new is: `class RacquetSport(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):` (you can omit `object`...).

Comment: Thank you!  I will make that change.

Comment: You wrote "My problem is that it seems like my play_game function is not correctly firing", but nowhere in your code do you call `play_game`. Why do you think it is being called?

Comment: If you are "new to OOP", I recommend you forget all about abstract classes and `__metaclass__` . In this specific case all they are doing is adding complexity without adding any value.

Comment: @BryanOakley I had just read that in a super class you could specify methods that had to be implemented using abstract classes.  Also, as far as the `play_game` when I add code in it still doesn't fire.  I had done some additional testing where I created an instance of the class and tried to get play_game to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you never call `play_game`. My guess is that you intend it to work like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    stats = SimStats()
    for x in range(1, 11):
        game = PingPong(.5, .5)
        game.play_game()
        stats.update(game)
    stats.print_results()
```

Next, you have a bug that will cause the entire game to last forever. Take a look at these lines:

```
def game_over(self):
    return self.player1.get_score == 11 or \
           self.player2.get_score == 11
```

`get_score` is a function, so you need to *call* it:

```
def game_over(self):
    return self.player1.get_score() == 11 or \
           self.player2.get_score() == 11
```